# Difference between passing parameter "params object array" and "object array"

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm currently coding an function of input object array, and have read many example, then I found these example in **EntityFrameworkCore** document:

```
public virtual ValueTask<TEntity?> FindAsync(params object?[]? keyValues)
public virtual ValueTask<TEntity?> FindAsync(object?[]? keyValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Is there any difference between the first input parameter of these two methods, **params object?[]?** and **object?[]?**

I have looked up many of introductions of **params** or other related articles, but not found any disscusion of the difference.

In particular I've read MSDN [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) says

> By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments. The parameter type must be a single-dimensional array.

and shows example of passing comma separated parameters in case of `params` :

```
public static void UseParams2(params object[] list){}
...
UseParams2(1, 'a', "test");
```

When I tried similar thing with method that does not specify `params` it failed to compile:

```
...FindAsync(1, 'a', "test", CancellationToken.None)
```

seems like **params** can be ignore?
Does someone know the difference between them? or they are exactly the same meaning?

Comment: yeah, thanks for adding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With params:

```
FindAsync(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Without params:

```
FindAsync(new object[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }, src.Token);
```

Comment: I know the difference now! thank you so much!